# Cannot accept Consumer<? extends Event>

Tags: java, consumer

I don't really know if this is possible but I've been trying to accept a `Consumer<? extends Event>` for a while, but I keep getting a variable mismatch whenever invoking it.

Here is my example code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Consumer<? extends Event>> x = new ArrayList<>();
    Consumer<ExampleEvent> y = e -> {}; // ExampleEvent extends Event
    x.add(y);
    for (Consumer<? extends Event> z : x) {
        z.accept(new Event());
    }
}
```

Every time I get an error saying that it's an argument mismatch

I'm using eclipse on windows

here is the error: `The method accept(capture#5-of ? extends Event) in the type Consumer<capture#5-of ? extends Event> is not applicable for the arguments (Event)`

Comment: You should read about PECS (producer extends consumer super)

Comment: Also read: [generics are invariant in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po/2745301#2745301).

Answer (score 0):

This code won't work because you are passing in arguments of the wrong type. `y` in this case is a `Consumer<ExampleEvent>`, which means that the signature of its `accept` override would be:

```
void accept(ExampleEvent e);
```

When you call `z.accept(new Event())` you are passing in an object of the wrong type. `Event` is not a subclass of `ExampleEvent`.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine if `z` is of type `SubEvent`. Where `SubEvent extends Event`. In this case, the call `z.accept(new Event())` is wrong. The method `accept()` expects a parameter of type `SubEvent` or its subclasses, not superclasses.